# how to display items one after one in custom layout using Asynocronous task in android

Tags: android, class, asynchronous, background-process

i am creating one layout in code retrieve all message string and image using webservices all retrieve data in background process display the data total all views display one time ,

my intension is i am getting  one message  string and one  image getting after display custom layout next getting another(second) message string  and image then display add the layout this functionality running one by one show the messages and images

xmlfile:

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"     
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"     
 android:background="@android:color/white"   
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">   
  <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1"   
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">  
    </ScrollView>
 </FrameLayout>
```

code file :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

    ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1); 

    LinearLayout topLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this); 
    topLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);  

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++){ 

        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this); 
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);  

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView (this); 
        TextView textView = new TextView (this); 

        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image); 
        textView.setText("Text View #" + i); 

        linearLayout.addView(imageView); 
        linearLayout.addView(textView); 

        topLinearLayout.addView(linearLayout);           

    } 

    scrollView.addView(topLinearLayout); 

}
```

how can display image and message in custom layout one after one in dynamically 
please forward some solution  thank in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using asynronous task in u r application update to ui

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this(in my point of view) is to create a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) with an custom Adapter (extend BaseAdapter, see documentation) and when you get another assynchronous message update the data on the list and call notifyDataSetChanged() from the adapter to redraw the list.

You are not doing the way it is supposed to be in Android.

Hope it helped!

Comment: hi already using customlayout total code file implemented dynamically implemented one by one tell me  some idea about this question